# Transaction on etherscan vanished

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, pending-transactions

Anyway i saw my transaction of eth on etherscan, thought looking good.
so put laptop away for 10 minutes and waited for it to clear into my Metamask.
After just 10 a 20 minutes went back and saw that the transaction now had just totally disappeared from etherscan. Nothing either in my metamask wallet. nothing to see that i ever made the transaction, except the tokens being gone from the exchange i sent them from. Going out my mind trying to find them PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: The title cracked me up!

Answer (score 1):

The title cracked me up!

But sorry for your loss!

Have you mentioned the correct address in the exchange when you are sending the money to the exchange? And the directed to the correct chain? For example, ERC20 and BEP20 for binance etc.

If you have mentioned the correct address and still haven't gotten the money, don't worry much about it.

Write a mail to exchange. Since the exchange is showing only the database in the front end, they can retrieve your funds if you haven't entered wrong address.

Comment: Cheers m8, for the quick response. really appreciate it. but yeah, adres etc all correct. had already done 2 other transactions prior to the lost one a day earlier, and they went through fine. so i am a bit set back by it all. maybe i need to be a bit more patient, and all will be well in a day or two. we will see.

Comment: Write a mail to the exchange or approach them through twitter. They can help you!

Comment: That's true, the title was a bit funny.